# How can I make Tomcat accept unescaped brackets in URLs?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, url

I've never used Tomcat before, but I've recently inherited a JSP project and now I need to get it running. I've managed to install Tomcat 8.0 locally in Eclipse and everything works fine. I've also installed Tomcat 8.0 on an Ubuntu VPS. The app is running fine, except for a small issue with how it handles URLs.

The client-side application produces URLs with unescaped square and curly brackets in parameters, like this:

```
GET /saveItems.json?items=[{%22json%22:%22here%22}]
```

As much as I would like to change the client-side app, I can't. I just need to get this backend running.

My local copy of the application handles this fine. On the server, however, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(AbstractNioInputBuffer.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1460)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've been looking for a setting that might affect this, without any luck. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 17):

I make this workable by editing $CATALINA_HOME\conf\server.xml

**Old Value:** `<Connector ... protocol="HTTP/1.1"... />`

**New Value:** `<Connector ... protocol="HTTP/1.1"... relaxedQueryChars='[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;' />`

Comment: You forgot to include the values

Comment: I replicate the above thing in server.xml file to allow #.But still tomcat not able to parse url  relaxedQueryChars="^{}|[]_#" and im using tomcat 8.5.27

Comment: Heads up that, depending on your use case, you may also want to use relaxedPathChars instead of relaxedQueryChars. See https://vividcode.io/support-brackets-in-url-query-string-with-tomcat/

Answer (score 8):

`Tomcat 8.0.39/8.5.9/7.0.73` add additional checks for valid characters to the HTTP request line parsing.
According to [this requirement](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60594), `version 8.0.42/8.5.12/7.0.76` make some changes to allow some invalid characters.
`{`, `}` and `|` are allowed if the character present in value of system property
`tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow`.

You can add system property `tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow={}` to prevent this error. One of the soltion is editing `$CATALINA_HOME\conf\catalina.properties`.

Comment: in tomcat 9.0.11 + tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow iused anymore. Use relaxedQueryChars only.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing a similar problem, but using Spring boot too, the following solution resolved my issue:

```
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "|{}[]");
        }
    });
return factory;
}
```

Credited to [Matthias-lohr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2400785/matthias-lohr) - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251131/invalid-character-found-in-the-request-target-in-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51608206/3944040)

Answer (score 2):

I get this error when I try to `GET URL` with some special character.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the
>   request target.

By changing the connector parameter in `server.xml`,
we are able to parse a special character in Tomcat version 9.

```
Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" relaxedQueryChars="\ { } |"
```