# Invalid character found in the request target in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

My application is started with java -jar with version 1.5.6.RELEASE of spring boot.
The content of one of my request has the character "{".When it is sended to server the following exception is raised:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the
>   request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC
>   3986  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Where is wrong?
How do I fix it?

EDIT1:
My rest is like this:

```
var jsonData = {
                    id: $("#hiddenId").val(),
                    permitNumber: $("#txtPermitNumber").val(),
                    permitToDate: $("#txtPermitToDate").val()
               }
document.location = restUrl + "/print?reportParams= " + JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html, *requestTargetAllow* is deprecated. For me, the other solutions presented here did not work either. According to the Tomcat documentation I found a way to set the property *relaxedQueryChars* instead:

```
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "|{}[]");
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: where I can find this configure in eclipse? @Matthias Lohr

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "find". This is code for a Java Bean. There's nothing Eclipse related here.

Comment: Thank you, this config works great for me

Answer (score 18):

For a Spring Boot application, just add to properties file:

```
server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=|,{,},[,]
```

There is also the following key: `server.tomcat.relaxed-path-chars`

Answer (score 11):

you will start your Spring boot app like this

```
$ java -jar -Dtomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}
 demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

or encode uri like this

```
document.location = restUrl + "/print?reportParams= " + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

Comment: dahanetoon service :D

Comment: Does not work for me, seems to be ignored with Spring Boot 2.x.

Answer (score 6):

if you use application.yaml just add following config

```
server:
  tomcat:
    relaxed-query-chars: '|,{,},[,]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way just add this code in your main class

`System.setProperty("tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow", "{}");`

Comment: Does (also) not work for me, seems to be ignored with Spring Boot 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

For SpringBoot 1.5.17.RELEASE. The below code worked for me.

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory webServerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector connector) {
                connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "|{}[]");
            }
        });
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Better if the user also gives the reason for down vote.

Comment: I did not vote to the post. I suspect, it did not work by the voter, what could have happened because he is using spring boot 2. But don't worry on it, the upvote is 5 times stronger than the down. If your solution will work by me, I will vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

For a Spring Boot application, have this in properties file:

server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=xercesImpl.jar,xml-apis.jar,serializer.jar,xml-apis.jar,jaxb-core.jar,jaxb-api.jar

Answer (score -1):

Encode it to Base 64 string at request end and decode it at the controller end.

---

Encode

`btoa(string)`

---

Decode:

```
String arr = request.getParameter();
arr = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(arr))
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and for me the problem was solved by replacing `@GetMapping` by `@PostMapping`.